# Git Restore -- Is this all I need for my usecase?

Tags: git, github, git-checkout, git-reset, git-revert

If I want to simply go back to an old commit, without losing any of my commit history, is this the easiest and safest way?

```
git restore --source 1f26124 :/
git add .
git commit -m "back to 1f26124"
```

From my understanding:

The first command is saying change my working view (specified by *git restore*) to go back to the specified commit hash (specified by *--source 1f26124*) for everything in the current branch (specified by *:/*).

Then with the next two lines, I'm committing everything to a new commit.

This allows me take my entire branch back to an old commit without losing anything. Is that right? Arguably the safest way to do so? Git Reset and Git Revert was a bit confusing to me but this seems actually perfect for all of my personal use cases unless I'm misunderstanding what this is doing.

Comment: Please don't use custom git aliases like `acm` when posting git-related questions. Did the `acm` alias come from https://gist.github.com/codexico/2a34c0d599f3af93b46f (`!f() { git add . && git commit -m \"$(echo $@)\"; }; f`) ?

Comment: Oh sorry, I must have added it a long time ago and thought it was a default command. It's just add all and commit. "!git add . && git commit -m"

Comment: _Is that right?_ Yes. `git restore` if I'm not mistaken a new command and I have never used it before, so personally I'd think that `git revert --no-edit 1f26124..` is preferable (it generates a series of commits, however, not squashing everything into a single commit). A bit of more: I also think that `git add --all` is even closer to your scenario since it would add all changes to the index, not the only ones starting from the current directory.

Comment: By the way, one you commit the "back to 1f26124" commit, you can make sure it's done right by `git diff 1f26124..@` that must generate zero differences between commits as both commit trees must be equal now.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't realize there was a difference between add --all and 'add .'. The git diff command you posted seems to return nothing as expected. Would you happen to know how I could alias this in such a way where I only have to put in (after the alias) the hash and the commit message? I.E "git flashback 1f26124 "going back to 1f26124"

Comment: Just add `flashback = "!f() { git restore --source "$1" :/ && git add --all && git commit --no-edit -m \"going back to $1\"; }; f"` to the `[alias]` section in your config file. If no argument provided, it will fail due to a missing argument for `git restore`. Not sure how `:/` works there and if it's able to work properly from a subdirectory.

Comment: Thanks! This is great. Works perfectly. `:/` seems to work even if I'm in a subdirectory which gets deleted in the commit I'm "flashing" to. It'll still delete itself to mimic the specific commit. At which point my shell is still in the deleted subfolder and I can't use git commands until I 'cd ..' Which is expected and makes sense.

Comment: I made a small typo: the git-restore argument is not properly escaped. Please change it from `"$1"` to `\"$1\"`

Comment: Got it. Thanks. Posting for future reference `flashback = "!f() { git restore --source \"$1\" :/ && git add --all && git commit --no-edit -m \"going back to $1\"; }; f"`